# How can I add extra information to a CNN in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to add some extra information to a CNN as gender, age, a vector...

My CNN have as inputs matrices that represent voice histograms with dimensions 125x64. Since they are from different persons, I would like to add that information to the model. Besides, I would like to add some vector 125x1 who represents the pitch or the energy of the voice (getting from feature extraction) but I think is not a good idea to attach it to the histogram.

```
 model = Sequential()

 model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='valid', strides=1,
             input_shape=input_shape, activation='relu'))

 model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4, 3), strides=(1, 3)))

 model.add(Conv2D(32, (1, 3), padding='valid', strides=1,
      input_shape=input_shape, activation='relu'))

 model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 3), strides=(1, 3)))

 model.add(Flatten())
 model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
 model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
 model.add(Dropout(0.5))

 model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
 model.add(Activation('softmax'))

 model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer='adadelta',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 1):

It indeed doesn't make much sense to add that data to the histogram. Keras has an explanation in their own documentation to how you use multiple inputs in a model: https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/. The paragraph **Multi-input and multi-output models** seems to be what you're looking for.